How use multiple app routers using AutoRoute
My project uses a package structure using melos. I have a my_app in apps/my_app. Also I have a package game in packages/game.
MyApp has an AppRouter, which is responsible for the router configuration. The Game library has its own AppRouter. MyApp's home screen uses a Banner widget that belongs to the Game package. When you click on it, you go to another route, which belongs to the Game package:
onTap: () async {
              await context.router.push(
                MyGamesRoute(tillStart: tillStart),
              );
          },

But now it doesn't work because the context.router contains the MyApp router. I need the Game package router to start being used at this moment.
